# Check if a Data URL represents an empty image

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas, gd, data-url

In a program I wrote, HTML5 canvas data are converted to *data-url* with `toDataURL()` and stored in a database. Now I want to determine which of these PNG images are blank (all bits transparent).

Is there any way I can determine that with Javascript or PHP?

Comment: resize the canvas to 1px X 1px, and check the A channel of that pixel for zero

Comment: @dandavis As I read it, the questioner wants to compare data urls pulled from a database--not live canvases. :-)

Comment: @markE Yes. You are right.

Comment: one would need to load the image into a canvas, even an invisible one, in order to read the pixel info with the built-in canvas api. you might be able to do it by looking at just the bytes without "mounting" it in a canvas, but there's a lot of ways to make a blank image, so i'm not sure how well that would work...